# finding a hemisphere that contains all points of a given set S

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

Let $S$ be a finite set of points on the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$. My question would be: is there an easy way to either find a great circle $C$ such that all points in $S$ are inside one of the hemispheres defined by $C$ or return that such a great circle does not exist.

This can of course also be seen as a problem in 3D, i.e. does there exist a plane through the origin, such that one of the halfplanes contains all of the points.

The only thing I could think of was like a "perceptron" style algorithm, but I'm not sure, if that algorithm would terminate, if a solution exists and also when to stop if it does not exist.

Does anyone have a "more sophisticated" idea?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think that computing the convex hull of $S$ and checking if the origin is inside of it may do the trick.

Comment: I think that this would work too! thanks. Now the question that remains is: how to get the great circle/plane that induces the hemisphere/halfspace. I think I could solve it using a linear program but it seems like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Comment: There is nothing overkill about using linear programming. In fixed dimension, it has linear complexity, that's faster than computing the convex hull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Nathaniel, first find the convex hull of $S$. Now note that there would exist a plane of the convex hull with the *property* that its one side contains all the points in $S$ and the other side contains the origin.
Let this plane be $ax + by + cz = d$. Then, the plane passing through the origin would be $ax + by +cz = 0$; it would induce the required halfspace.

You can get the plane $ax + by + cz = d$ by finding the convex hull in $O(n \log n)$ and verifying the property for each plane in $O(n)$ time.